# How to find the rotation components between two similar trirectangular tetrahedrons?

Tags: edit-mode, snapping

I have two trirectangular tetrahedrons like on the following screenshot. My goal is to find the roll pitch yaw rotation components between the two.

[image]

One of them has its 3 orthogonal edges along X, Y and Z as you see on the picture. The second one has it's top vertex on the origin like the first one, but it has been rotated around all 3 axis.

An idea I tried is using the snap tool, to rotate the object and to snap it to the other one, but I couldn't find how to do that.

-- EDIT --
How can I rotate the first one so that it gets exactly superimposed with the second one ?
After that I'll be able to directly read the 3 rotation values in the right menu, which I'm interested in.

As an approximation of the result I want, I can rotate it manually and get approximative values by eye (see screenshot below with values in the red circle), but is there a way to get exact values ?

[image]

Thanks !

Comment: Sounds like a test more than a question... Just delete the second shape. Then select the first one and duplicate it. BOOM... done.

Comment: @Dontwalk But that won't give me the rotation values around XYZ ? I want to find those 3 values so that when applied on the first object, it rotates it exactly as the second one. Do you see what I mean ?